# How to access value from filter in angular

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am using `Kendo Grid 3.6.0` and `Angular 6`

Below is the filter I am trying to enter for AssetName column in Kendo Grid

[image: Kendo Grid Column]

How to get `value` of `A254` in the screenshot above into a new variable

Comment: var variable = filters[0].filters[0].value

Comment: It is throwing error `undefined` for second `filters` even though it is having the value as in the screenshot in the Question.

Comment: Can we access through `map` function?

Comment: Try filter.filters[0].filters[0].value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const newVariable = ((<any>(<CompositeFilterDescriptor>filter.filters[0]).filters[0]).value);
```